# In TradingView, Pinescript, receiving this error: Error at 5:10 Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

My code :

```
//@version=5

indicator ("Trigger Lines Trend Definition", overlay=true)

import ta

// Indicator inputs
band_length = input.int(title="Band Length", defval=10)
band_mult = input.float(title="Band Multiplier", defval=1.5)

// Calculate the band
basis = ta.sma(close, band_length)
dev = band_mult * ta.stdev(close, band_length)
upper_band = basis + dev
lower_band = basis - dev

// Define body
body = abs (close - open)

// Determine trend direction
up_trend = close > upper_band and ta.median(close - open, band_length) > (upper_band - basis) and close > high[1] and body >= body[1]
down_trend = close < lower_band and ta.median(open - close, band_length) > (basis - lower_band) and close < low[1] and body >= body[1]

// Plot the ribbon
fill(upper_band, lower_band, color=up_trend ? color.green : down_trend ? color.red : color.gray)

// Add horizontal lines to visualize the band
plot(upper_band, color=color.blue)
plot(lower_band, color=color.blue)

// Plot signals
signalColor = up_trend ? color.green : down_trend ? color.red : color.black
plotshape(series=up_trend, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=signalColor, size=size.small, title="Up Trend")
plotshape(series=down_trend, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=signalColor, size=size.small, title="Down Trend")

// Create alerts
alertcondition(up_trend, title="Up Trend", message="New uptrend detected")
alertcondition(down_trend, title="Down Trend", message="New downtrend detected")
```

Tried several combinations of listed solutions, different indent spacing, added/removed lines, and many suggested solutions online. Disclaimer: beginner with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It is the `import ta` which is the cause.
But there are other error in your code.

Here is a working version :

```
//@version=5

indicator ("Trigger Lines Trend Definition", overlay=true)


// Indicator inputs
band_length = input.int(title="Band Length", defval=10)
band_mult = input.float(title="Band Multiplier", defval=1.5)

// Calculate the band
basis = ta.sma(close, band_length)
dev = band_mult * ta.stdev(close, band_length)
upper_band = basis + dev
lower_band = basis - dev

// Define body
body = math.abs (close - open)

// Determine trend direction
up_trend = close > upper_band and ta.median(close - open, band_length) > (upper_band - basis) and close > high[1] and body >= body[1]
down_trend = close < lower_band and ta.median(open - close, band_length) > (basis - lower_band) and close < low[1] and body >= body[1]



// Add horizontal lines to visualize the band
Line_Upper = plot(upper_band, color=color.blue)
Liner_Lower = plot(lower_band, color=color.blue)

// Plot the ribbon
fill(Line_Upper, Liner_Lower, color=up_trend ? color.green : down_trend ? color.red : color.gray)

// Plot signals
signalColor = up_trend ? color.green : down_trend ? color.red : color.black
plotshape(series=up_trend, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=signalColor, size=size.small, title="Up Trend")
plotshape(series=down_trend, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=signalColor, size=size.small, title="Down Trend")

// Create alerts
alertcondition(up_trend, title="Up Trend", message="New uptrend detected")
alertcondition(down_trend, title="Down Trend", message="New downtrend detected")
```